# html сущности в ссылке

Tags: html, apache

есть ссылки типа `http://example.com/?cat&amp;amp;amp;data`
два вопроса:
1. допустимы ли сущности в ссылках? в rfc такого не видел
2. браузер из подобной конструкции `&amp;amp;amp;` (независимо от того, где она на странице находится) делает такое: `&amp;amp;` очевидно не ожидая более одного `amp;`. Все остальные `amp;` выводит как есть. Проверка ссылки с "остаткими" `amp;` и без них ведёт на одну и ту же страницу, так ли это всегда или нет? как ведёт себя апач или иной сервер видя эти хвосты?

P.S. я понимаю, что веб мастерам надо руки оторвать и т.д., исходим из того, что это есть

Comment: Во-первых, html-сущности не имеют никакого отношения ни к ссылкам, ни к серверам, они просто задают значение атрибута в html-элементе, и это значение в вашем случае — `http://example.com/?cat&amp;amp;data`. Во-вторых, у вас здесь одна-единственная сущность `&amp;`, а `amp;` и `amp;` очевидно не являются html-сущностями. Если вы хотите три амперснда подряд, должно быть `http://example.com/?cat&amp;&amp;&amp;data`  — это будет ссылка `http://example.com/?cat&&&data`. На сервер никаких html-сущностей вообще не передаётся — они существуют только в html-коде.

Comment: 1. хорошо, по другому спрошу: ссылка - ```http://example.com/?cat&amp;amp;amp;data``` браузером превращается в ```http://example.com/?cat&amp;amp;data``` и это не отображение юзеру, браузер при переходе укажет именно такую ссылку, апач или иной сервер видя такое в ссылке ```&amp;amp;``` поведёт себя как браузер или буквально распарсит ссылку?

Comment: Буквально распарсит ссылку. Сервер — не браузер, а ссылка — не html-код.